# Using JQuery to change order of elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to alter the order on which some images show, I want the images to shift to the right/left one spot every time I hit a button. This is what I've tried but no luck.

Any help or insight will be truly appreciated

```
$("#rightShift").click(function(){
    $("img").hide();
    var count = $("img").size();
    $("img").each(function(i) { 
        var indexImg = count - i;
        $("img:eq(indexImg)").show();
    });
}); 
$("#leftShift").click(function(){
    $("img").hide();
    $("img:last").prependTo("img");
    $("img").show();
});
```

Comment: Tip: A block of code has to be prefixed by a newline. Every line of code in the block of code has to be prefixed by four spaces. Backticks should only be used for inline code.

Comment: Can you post html relevant to that part?

Comment: Does this work like a carousel that goes around? That is, does the last image become the first one when you are shifting right?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you want this to work like a carousel that goes around (the last image become the first one when you are shifting right), then this is how I would do it:

```
$("#rightShift").click(function(){
    $("img:last").detach().insertBefore("img:first");
});

$("#leftShift").click(function(){
    $("img:first").detach().insertAfter("img:last");
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thank you very much. I just edited the rightShift function so that it inserts before the first item, the way you had it it was inserting after the first item and that one wasn't being changed. But thanks again for pointing me on the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to refer to a variable inside a string. That makes no sense.
You actually meant:

```
$("img:eq(" + indexImg + ")").show();
```

But a more efficient implementation is:

```
$(this).prev().show();
```

The most efficient implementation without side-effects is:

```
$("#rightShift").click(function(){
    var $images = $("img"); // <-- Reference to all images
    $images.hide();
    //var count = $images.length; //<-- Unused variable, delete it?
    $images.each(function(i) { 
        $(this).prev().show();
    });
}); 
$("#leftShift").click(function() {
    var $images = $("img");
    $images.hide();
    $images.last().prependTo("img"); // OR: $images.before($images.last());
    $images.show();
});
```

Comment: In case you're wondering why I replaced `$("img")` with `$images`: `$("img")` is a relatively expensive function. The collection is assumed to be constant throughout the function, so you should cache the collection in a variable. An anology: When you build a house, you will keep the nails with you, instead of throwing them away, and going to the shop to buy new ones when you need them.

Comment: The implementation might work but is not the most efficient...You're declaring `var $images = $("img");` twice for no reason, just declare it outside. And you should chain all those `$images` calls like so `$images.hide().each();` and `$images.hide().last().prependTo('img').end().show();`

Comment: @elclanrs Your implementation has side-effects. You assume the number of images to be constant at all times, while it's also possible that images are added/removed between the page load, and the click event. Storing the collection in a variable is less expensive than a function call (`.end()`).

Comment: Oh, you're right about that but still, I think you should chain those calls.

Comment: @elclanrs In this case, chaining is equivalent to using a temporary variable. This is just a matter of preference, and since the OP didn't chain, I didn't either. When jQuery methods are chained, the code is harder to update, because you can't squeeze another method between, without looking up the source of the chain.

Comment: Mmm...it must be personal preferences then.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$("img:eq(indexImg)").show();
```

Should be this:

```
$("img:eq(" + indexImg + ")").show();
```

Not sure if other stuff is wrong though.