# JS/jQuery/CSS --- Change elements horizontal order with any of those?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got an interactive module with 3 elements. All of those boxes have an `onClick` handler that sets its class as active and change some texts around.

The question is - if those elements are horizontally aligned, is there any way to change their order? I'd like the `active` class element to be always displayed on the right side.

[image: Three horizontal elements]

Comment: Yes, there are some ways. What have you tried for it?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JQuery to change order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243956/using-jquery-to-change-order-of-elements)

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee I Know This Can Be Done With Flex Box But It Id Not Supported By All browsers right? What would you say about float left/right it The wrapper for them was well developed?

Comment: I don't ever heard `Flex Box`. Read the post I comment as duplicate. It is jquery! Read it. If it does not help, Prepare a working example of your codes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
$('class').css('float','right');
```